# Performance of different math functions in x86?

Tags: c++, performance, math, floating-point

I am writing a 3D collision, and want to know the difference in performance of basic math functions like + - * / sqrt pwr trigonometry like sin cos tan arcsin..

I heard it depends on many other things so I just want to get a rough idea about which one is slower and need to avoid while finding different ways to solve the problem. Also I want to know the order and the magnitude of the difference

Thanks

Edit: I write in VC++ for x86. But knowledge in other architectures and general picture are good, too. Mainly I calculate in single floating point for real time application.

The problem is that some algorithms need sqrt, or trigonometry, but I can bypass them by other methods. Each one has its own advances and I want to know is enough to do trade off. I want a general knowledge to solve my own problem, did a google but found nothing so please let it be answered

Comment: Why not benchmark it yourself? Write programs that do a bunch of whatever operator/function you want to benchmark, and have it print out the time taken.

Comment: Depends on a million things really, what target cpu? what compiler? fixed point or floating point? what calculations since some will be optimized into something completely different etc.

Comment: Draft you algorithm a bit, ask questions as you encounter problems, we'll all benefit from the input.

Comment: @code-gijoe: No, this good general knowledge to have. This is a good question and should be voted up and not closed.

Comment: @Postpi, I vote up to encourage the guy.

Comment: depending on accuracy, a common trick is to tabulate trig functions (every degree or less)

Answer (score 6):

Speaking very broadly, and generalizing about recent common hardware:

- addition, subtraction and multiplication are fast (capable of at least one operation per cycle per core).
- division and square root are typically about an order of magnitude slower (tens of cycles per operation).  There are many approximation algorithms that can be used to narrow this gap somewhat for specific usages.
- calling math library functions (`sin`, `cos`, `exp`, `log`, etc) varies significantly depending on what math library implementation you are using and on what hardware.  On (say) a current i7, something between an operation every ~20 cycles and an operation every ~200 cycles is typical, depending on the quality of the implementation and the specific function being called.

Comment: Also, `float` versions may be faster than `double` versions for complicated math library functions.

Comment: I wonder, don't current CPUs have the LUTs for sin/cos/… in their FPU?

Comment: @JonasWielicki: In general, no.  The x86 architecture has hardware support for sin/cos, but it's significantly slower than a good software implementation, and as far as I am aware it is not based on a LUT.  Most non-x86 platforms (ARM, PPC, etc) don't have any such instructions at all.

Comment: Ok, nice to know. I assumed the FPU to be faster than a software implementation—does the hardware have better accuracy or is there no reason at all to use it?

Comment: @JonasWielicki: there's no good reason to use it today.  It exists for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting the effects of bitshifts (<<, >>). Especially in regards to division. While it may be tens of cycles in the general case, integer division by powers of two can be done in one cycle.

Comment: @Jason: in this context, the questioner is probably asking about floating-point operations, for which division is not equivalent to shifts (but division by powers of two can be replaced with multiplication by the inverse).

Answer (score 2):

For a rough idea: `+, -` < `*` < `/` < `sqrt` < `sin, cos, etc`

PS. On recent Intel architectures:

ADDSD/SUBSD - 3     cycles latency,     1 cycle  throughput

MULSD       - 6-7   cycles latency,     2 cycles throughput

DIVSD       - 38-39 cycles latency, 38-39 cycles throughput

Comment: For most practical purposes, on most modern hardware the performance of addition and multiplication are equivalent; the latencies may differ, but the throughput is generally balanced.

Comment: Also, you can have dedicated hardware for `sqrt` and non-algebraic functions too (like `sin`, `exp`, `log`), which - IIRC - will return a floating-point approximation in one CPU cycle.

Comment: @H2CO3: I know of no hardware implementation of transcendental functions that's capable of delivering a result in a single cycle; the most commonly used hardware implementations (the Intel x87 instructions) are single-instruction *but actually significantly slower than good software implementations* -- on the order of 100-200 cycles according to the Intel Optimization Manual.

Comment: @StephenCanon Yes, I meant single-**cycle** and not only single-**instruction** - I'm sure there exist some as well. But well, I trust compiler and libc creators to be proficient enough in optimization.

Comment: @chill: the Intel numbers you listed are for the NetBurst micro-architecture which is 12 years old.  Current numbers are 3:1 for ADDSD/SUBSD, 5:1 for MULSD, and 20:14 for DIVSD according to Intel's manuals.

Comment: @StephenCanon, OK, not "recent", still the general relation holds and not only for Intel CPUs.