# Benchmark mathematical operations with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, benchmarking

Code running faster is always a plus. If I want to build a code to perform some numerical simulation, more often than not, I will have the possibility of unfolding an equation into "primitive" operations.

I have been wondering what is the computational cost of some mathematical operations:

- summation
- subtraction
- multiplication
- division
- squaring
- trigonometric functions (e.g., sin)

I have created the following script to measure this operations:

```
# Import necessary modules
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define functions to test
def summation(value):
    return value+value
    
def subtraction(value):
    return value-value

def multiplication(value):
    return value*value

def division(value):
    return value/2

def square(value):
    return value**2
    
def sin(value):
    return np.sin(value)

# Function that will evaluate the execution time
def time_execution(func, valueToEvaluate, nOuterCycles, nCycles):
    store = np.zeros( nOuterCycles)
    for i in range( nOuterCycles):
        start = time.time()
        for j in range(nCycles):
            func(valueToEvaluate)
        end = time.time()
        store[i]=(end-start)
    
    meanCycleTime=np.round(np.mean(store)*1e9/nCycles)
    stdCycleTime=np.round(np.std(store)*1e9/nCycles,2)
    print("%s takes %s ns.\u00B1 %s ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of %s runs %s loops each)" %(func.__name__,meanCycleTime,stdCycleTime,nOuterCycles,nCycles))
    return func.__name__,meanCycleTime,stdCycleTime

# Time execution parameters
nCycles=1000000
nOuterCycles=5
value=1.1

# Executes the functions and appends the results to a list
valuesForPlot=[]
valuesForPlot.append(time_execution(summation,value,nOuterCycles,nCycles))
valuesForPlot.append(time_execution(subtraction,value,nOuterCycles,nCycles))
valuesForPlot.append(time_execution(multiplication,value,nOuterCycles,nCycles))
valuesForPlot.append(time_execution(division,value,nOuterCycles,nCycles))
valuesForPlot.append(time_execution(square,value,nOuterCycles,nCycles))
valuesForPlot.append(time_execution(sin,value,nOuterCycles,nCycles))

    
## Bar plot
# Collect entries for the plot
x_names =  []
y_values = []
error =    []

for i in valuesForPlot:
    x_names.append(i[0])
    y_values.append(i[1])
    error.append(i[2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x_names, y_values, yerr=error,align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black', capsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('Time of operation [s]')
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

On my computer, the results I are the following:

```
summation takes 85.0 ns.± 2.99 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs 1000000 loops each)
subtraction takes 82.0 ns.± 2.25 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs 1000000 loops each)
multiplication takes 74.0 ns.± 0.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs 1000000 loops each)
division takes 85.0 ns.± 1.52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs 1000000 loops each)
square takes 103.0 ns.± 2.06 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs 1000000 loops each)
sin takes 779.0 ns.± 2.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs 1000000 loops each)
```

I have read online (https://streamhpc.com/blog/2012-07-16/how-expensive-is-an-operation-on-a-cpu/, and in other sites ) that math operations I have chosen should be ranked in the following order:
summation and subtraction < multiplication < division < squaring < trignometric functions. However, the results I am getting for summation,subtraction, multiplication and division do not have a substantial difference. Any particular reason why?

Best regards

Comment: Change `2` in your division into variable and it should take longer to compute.Similarly, `a*a` might be faster than `a*b`.

Comment: The time taken to merely call these functions is probably overwhelming the time taken to evaluate these simple math operations.

Comment: The time a single operation takes is negligible. The first step to make things faster, is invoke numpy with array operations. Avoid loops. Possibly an approach such as numba to compile to machine code. ....

Comment: Also notice that python has arbitrary size integers, so you will see a more noticeable difference with larger numbers.

Comment: If speed matters, use a native language like C++, not Python. Python is useless for this sort of performance measurement since the overhead of the interpreter far outweighs the cost of basic arithmetic operations. On x86, addition, subtraction, and multiplication execute one operation per cycle per core, or in other words, these operations cost a fraction of a nanosecond on a modern machine (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847167/performance-of-different-math-functions-in-x86).